# How can we add Alter session queries in Tableau to improve performance

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to use alter queries in Initial sql (Tableau) but it is giving an error. My data has around 500 000 rows which is taking very long time for retrieving the data into tableau. Is there any way to make this process faster?

Comment: How do your tables work and how do you query it?

You can either optimise the query or increase the performance of the DB oracle by adding more resources (CPU memory).

If you have 500,000 rows across hundreds of tables that you JOIN or you do subqueries on, it can take a long time

Comment: "very long time" can be hugely different for different people. Please don't be vague when there's no need to.